# Show and Hide markers drawingManager

Tags: hide, show, markers

Hi I have a trouble with map code... I use drawingManager to create marks but I want to show or hide depending on a checkbox but I have no idea how to do this... can someone help!! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you need 3 parts of code to do this.

1) Below is the code for display layer (I assume you have this already):

```
var parcel_boundary = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
query: {
    select: 'parcel_boundary_1_9999',
    from: '1ouLS0fm8tPPQNQRpr-bwE4ct-cBkMB-Ru_XttDQ'
  },
  styles: [{
    polygonOptions: {
    strokeColor: "#333333",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 0.7,
    fillColor: "#36549C",
    fillOpacity: 0.3
    }
}],
    //map: map,
    suppressInfoWindows: true
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(parcel_boundary, 'click', function(e) {
    windowControl(e, infoWindow, map);
});
```

2) Immediately below display layer code comes this part of code:

```
$('#parcel_boundary_box').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    parcel_boundary.setMap(map); // show
    else
    parcel_boundary.setMap(null); // hide
    });
$('#parcel_boundary_box').removeAttr('disabled');
```

3) And inside body you need to add this code:

```
<div id="panel" style="position:absolute; left:560; top:0px; width:140px; height:30px;">
<input type="checkbox" id="parcel_boundary_box" disabled="true">
<span class="style2">Parcel Boundary</span> 
</div>
```

I hope I helped you.

Best,
Darko